# Reading bar codes using wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

In one of my WPF applications, I have the need to be able to read bar code values using C#.  I am not sure how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably not much to do with WPF

Comment: -1. Is that an issue with wpf, or with usb/other_port data reading, or with decyphering barcode data (in any format), or what?

Answer (score 10):

The best way is to create a keyboard hook.

Below is a class that I have used in several projects.

You use it like this:

```
var hook = new KeyboardHook();
var availbleScanners = KeyboardHook.GetKeyboardDevices();
... // find out which scanner to use 

hook.SetDeviceFilter(availableScanners.First());

hook.KeyPressed += OnBarcodeKey;

hook.AddHook(YourWPFMainView);

...

public void OnBarcodeKey(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("received " + e.Text);
}
```

---

I got the low level keyboard stuff from [this article](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/distinguishing-barcode-scanners-from-the-keyboard-in-winforms/).

```
  public class KeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
  {

    public KeyPressedEventArgs(string text) {
      mText = text;
    }
    public string Text { get { return mText; } }

    private readonly string mText;
  }

  public partial class KeyboardHook 
    : IDisposable
  {
    private static readonly Regex DeviceNamePattern = new Regex(@"#([^#]+)");
    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> KeyPressed;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the device to use in keyboard hook
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceId">Name of device</param>
    /// <returns>true if device is found</returns>
    public bool SetDeviceFilter(string deviceId) {
      Dictionary<string, IntPtr> devices = FindAllKeyboardDevices();
      return devices.TryGetValue(deviceId, out mHookDeviceId);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add this KeyboardHook to a window
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="window">The window to add to</param>
    public void AddHook(System.Windows.Window window) {
      if (window == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("window");
      if (mHwndSource != null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Hook already present");

      IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
      mHwndSource = HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd);
      if (mHwndSource == null)
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to receive window source");

      mHwndSource.AddHook(WndProc);

      RAWINPUTDEVICE[] rid = new RAWINPUTDEVICE[1];

      rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
      rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;
      rid[0].dwFlags = RIDEV_INPUTSINK;
      rid[0].hwndTarget = hwnd;

      if (!RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0])))
        throw new ApplicationException("Failed to register raw input device(s).");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove this keyboard hook from window (if it is added)
    /// </summary>
    public void RemoveHook() {
      if (mHwndSource == null)
        return; // not an error

      RAWINPUTDEVICE[] rid = new RAWINPUTDEVICE[1];

      rid[0].usUsagePage = 0x01;
      rid[0].usUsage = 0x06;
      rid[0].dwFlags = 0x00000001;
      rid[0].hwndTarget = IntPtr.Zero;

      RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0]));
      mHwndSource.RemoveHook(WndProc);
      mHwndSource.Dispose();
      mHwndSource = null;
    }

    public void Dispose() {
      RemoveHook();
    }

    private IntPtr mHookDeviceId;
    private HwndSource mHwndSource;

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) {
      switch (msg) {
        case WM_INPUT: 
          if (ProcessInputCommand(mHookDeviceId, lParam)) {
            MSG message;
            PeekMessage(out message, IntPtr.Zero, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYDOWN, PM_REMOVE);
          }
          break;
      }
      return IntPtr.Zero;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of keyboard devices available
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Collection of devices available</returns>
    public static ICollection<string> GetKeyboardDevices() {
      return FindAllKeyboardDevices().Keys;
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, IntPtr> FindAllKeyboardDevices() {
      Dictionary<string, IntPtr> deviceNames = new Dictionary<string, IntPtr>();
      uint deviceCount = 0;
      int dwSize = (Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)));

      if (GetRawInputDeviceList(IntPtr.Zero, ref deviceCount, (uint)dwSize) == 0) {
        IntPtr pRawInputDeviceList = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)(dwSize*deviceCount));

        try {
          GetRawInputDeviceList(pRawInputDeviceList, ref deviceCount, (uint)dwSize);

          for (int i = 0; i < deviceCount; i++) {
            uint pcbSize = 0;

            var rid = (RAWINPUTDEVICELIST)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                                            new IntPtr((pRawInputDeviceList.ToInt32() + (dwSize*i))),
                                            typeof(RAWINPUTDEVICELIST));

            GetRawInputDeviceInfo(rid.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, IntPtr.Zero, ref pcbSize);

            if (pcbSize > 0) {
              IntPtr pData = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)pcbSize);
              try {
                GetRawInputDeviceInfo(rid.hDevice, RIDI_DEVICENAME, pData, ref pcbSize);
                string deviceName = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pData);

                // The list will include the "root" keyboard and mouse devices
                // which appear to be the remote access devices used by Terminal
                // Services or the Remote Desktop - we're not interested in these
                // so the following code with drop into the next loop iteration
                if (deviceName.ToUpper().Contains("ROOT"))
                  continue;

                // If the device is identified as a keyboard or HID device,
                // Check if it is the one we're looking for
                if (rid.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD || rid.dwType == RIM_TYPEHID) {
                  Match match = DeviceNamePattern.Match(deviceName);
                  if (match.Success)
                    deviceNames.Add(match.Groups[1].Value, rid.hDevice);
                }
              }
              finally {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pData);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        finally {
          Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pRawInputDeviceList);
        }
      }
      return deviceNames;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Processes WM_INPUT messages to retrieve information about any
    /// keyboard events that occur.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="deviceId">Device to process</param>
    /// <param name="lParam">The WM_INPUT message to process.</param>
    private bool ProcessInputCommand(IntPtr deviceId, IntPtr lParam) {
      uint dwSize = 0;

      try {
        // First call to GetRawInputData sets the value of dwSize
        // dwSize can then be used to allocate the appropriate amount of memory,
        // storing the pointer in "buffer".
        GetRawInputData(lParam, RID_INPUT, IntPtr.Zero,ref dwSize, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)));

        IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)dwSize);
        try {
          // Check that buffer points to something, and if so,
          // call GetRawInputData again to fill the allocated memory
          // with information about the input
          if (buffer != IntPtr.Zero &&
              GetRawInputData(lParam, RID_INPUT, buffer, ref dwSize, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RAWINPUTHEADER))) == dwSize) {
            // Store the message information in "raw", then check
            // that the input comes from a keyboard device before
            // processing it to raise an appropriate KeyPressed event.

            RAWINPUT raw = (RAWINPUT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(buffer, typeof(RAWINPUT));

            if (raw.header.hDevice != deviceId)
              return false;

            if (raw.header.dwType != RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
              return false;
            if (raw.keyboard.Message != WM_KEYDOWN && raw.keyboard.Message != WM_SYSKEYDOWN)
              return false;

            // On most keyboards, "extended" keys such as the arrow or page 
            // keys return two codes - the key's own code, and an "extended key" flag, which
            // translates to 255. This flag isn't useful to us, so it can be
            // disregarded.
            if (raw.keyboard.VKey > VK_LAST_KEY)
              return false;

            if (KeyPressed != null) {
              string scannedText = null;
              lock (mLocalBuffer) {
                if (GetKeyboardState(mKeyboardState)) {
                  if (ToUnicode(raw.keyboard.VKey, raw.keyboard.MakeCode, mKeyboardState, mLocalBuffer, 64, 0) > 0) {
                    if (mLocalBuffer.Length > 0) {
                      scannedText = mLocalBuffer.ToString();
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(scannedText))
                KeyPressed(this, new KeyPressedEventArgs(scannedText));
            }
            return true;
          }
        }
        finally {
          Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception err) {
        Logger.LogError(err, "Scanner error");
      }
      return false;
    }
    private static readonly StringBuilder mLocalBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    private static readonly byte[] mKeyboardState = new byte[256];
  } 

 public partial class KeyboardHook
  {
    private const int RIDEV_INPUTSINK = 0x00000100;
    private const int RIDEV_REMOVE = 0x00000001;
    private const int RID_INPUT = 0x10000003;

    private const int FAPPCOMMAND_MASK = 0xF000;
    private const int FAPPCOMMAND_MOUSE = 0x8000;
    private const int FAPPCOMMAND_OEM = 0x1000;

    private const int RIM_TYPEMOUSE = 0;
    private const int RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD = 1;
    private const int RIM_TYPEHID = 2;

    private const int RIDI_DEVICENAME = 0x20000007;

    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x0104;
    private const int WM_INPUT = 0x00FF;
    private const int VK_OEM_CLEAR = 0xFE;
    private const int VK_LAST_KEY = VK_OEM_CLEAR; // this is a made up value used as a sentinal

    private const int PM_REMOVE = 0x01;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RAWINPUTDEVICELIST
    {
      public IntPtr hDevice;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public int dwType;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct RAWINPUT
    {
      [FieldOffset(0)]
      public RAWINPUTHEADER header;

      [FieldOffset(16)]
      public RAWMOUSE mouse;

      [FieldOffset(16)]
      public RAWKEYBOARD keyboard;

      [FieldOffset(16)]
      public RAWHID hid;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RAWINPUTHEADER
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public int dwType;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public int dwSize;

      public IntPtr hDevice;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public int wParam;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RAWHID
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public int dwSizHid;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public int dwCount;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct BUTTONSSTR
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public ushort usButtonFlags;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public ushort usButtonData;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct RAWMOUSE
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      [FieldOffset(0)]
      public ushort usFlags;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      [FieldOffset(4)]
      public uint ulButtons;

      [FieldOffset(4)]
      public BUTTONSSTR buttonsStr;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      [FieldOffset(8)]
      public uint ulRawButtons;

      [FieldOffset(12)]
      public int lLastX;

      [FieldOffset(16)]
      public int lLastY;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      [FieldOffset(20)]
      public uint ulExtraInformation;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RAWKEYBOARD
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public ushort MakeCode;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public ushort Flags;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public ushort Reserved;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public ushort VKey;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public uint Message;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public uint ExtraInformation;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RAWINPUTDEVICE
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public ushort usUsagePage;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)]
      public ushort usUsage;

      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
      public int dwFlags;

      public IntPtr hwndTarget;
    }

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceList(IntPtr pRawInputDeviceList, ref uint uiNumDevices, uint cbSize);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetRawInputDeviceInfo(IntPtr hDevice, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern bool RegisterRawInputDevices(RAWINPUTDEVICE[] pRawInputDevice, uint uiNumDevices, uint cbSize);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern uint GetRawInputData(IntPtr hRawInput, uint uiCommand, IntPtr pData, ref uint pcbSize, uint cbSizeHeader);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int ToUnicode(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeConst = 64)] StringBuilder pwszBuff,
                                         int cchBuff, uint wFlags);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool PeekMessage(out MSG lpmsg, IntPtr hwnd, uint wMsgFilterMin, uint wMsgFilterMax, uint wRemoveMsg);
  }
}
```

Comment: I had trubble with this under .NET 4. Found this comment on the article: You need to give your StringBuilder in ProcessRawInputMessage a capacity (it’s 16 by default), or the call to ToUnicode will crash under .NET 4.0.

Replace

localBuffer = new StringBuilder(); with localBuffer = new StringBuilder(64); It fixed my problems.

Comment: `hook.SetDeviceFilter(availableScanners.First());` But how do you sure the first device must be the barcode scanner?

Comment: @qakmak, by removing all others from the list :-)

Comment: The problem is if the user use it with the keyboard, some time reconnect the keyboard or put the keyboard after the barcode scanner,  `availableScanner.First()` will return the keyboard itself.  Is there anyway to avoid it? thanks.

Comment: I voted this up as with all the posts related to USB/POS to WPF out there, this has work most fluidly for me. I have this within a usercontrol inside MainWindow (MahApps Window)

Comment: I also use an "if" statement to check if returned e.Key is a return key(keybord enter) (in the OnBarcodeKey(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e) event ...) ... if(e.Key.ToString() == "13" && e.MakeCode.ToString() == "28") { istheEnd = true; doFinalTask();//return key? }else{ e.Key.ToString() += theBarcode;//append to the barcode string}

Comment: I also use (when inside a usercontrol(not a window)) a foreach on the MainWindow to delegate the hwnd error is used in a none window type.          foreach (System.Windows.Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
                    {

                        //add the hook to MainWindow
                        hook.AddHook((window as MainWindow));

                    }


                }

Answer (score 2):

Most of the barcode readers I've seen emulate a keyboard and send a key-press stream followed by a carriage return.

If your barcode reader works this way then a regular edit box should work.

Comment: ok thanks.. Will check this.. So as per your suggestion we don't need to much with wpf and it's upto the barcode reader..