# WPF textbox event capture multiple chars

Tags: c#, wpf, events, textbox

I have barcode scanner. I need to capture string from barcode into textbox. The final word in textbox will be composed of multiple codes from barcode scanner.
What event(s) should I use?

For example :
Barcode sends value `123` .

I tried `PreviewTextInput` event and `e.Text` but it captured only first char `1` . How can I get all added chars to textbox when I use barcode scanner?

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://dotnettrails.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/capturing-barcode-scan-using-c/  It gives you two options: Either use a timer to delay the text_changed event, or capture the enter key on the keyUp event (it assumes that the barcode scanner will send a carriage return at the end of the scan)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextBox does not lose anything. If `e.Text` is `"1"` then it only means that your scanner sends characters to `TextBox` one by one. Meaning you will get one event per character added.

Your approach is really wierd tho. `TextBox` knows nothing about barcodes, scanners. etc. It simply *displays text*. Why do you ask it, if your scanner finished scanning? That makes no sense. Leave poor `TextBox` alone. If you want to know when the scanning procces is finished, than you should add an appropriate event to class, which actually reads barcodes. And then, after this event fires, you should access the resulting string via `TextBox.Text` or using other means (forexample by accessing a viewmodel property).

**Edit:** the thing with wpf events, is that your control needs to have "keyboard focus", if you want it to recieve keyboard events. If you show a `MessageBox` then your `TextBox` loses focus and, as a result, no longer recieves events. Again, leave the `TextBox` alone. You need to write a dedicated class (i.e. `BarcodeReader`) which will handle keyboard events for you and then fire an event when the barcode is read. You can use [Keyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.aspx) class inside the `BarcodeReader` to handle buttons pressed.

Comment: actually it loses it some way...Barcode scanner work like it emulate the keyboard and it sends key-pressed stream.. I supposed I will get one event per character, but when it gets barcode (or string) contained from 3 characters, the event is raised only once and textbox also have contains 1st character in the end... when I don't use event it gets all 3 characters (in event I just have one `MessageBox.Show`)

Comment: hmm not exactly what I wanted but you directed me in better way, thanks.. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# in back end then you can have a look at this question: [Reading bar codes using wpf application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357010/reading-bar-codes-using-wpf-application)

Comment: my barcode works like that I suppose it emulate keyboard, so it sends stream of chars (or stream of some keypressed events) into the textbox.. When I don't use any event on textbox and use scanner then (f.e. I send code `123`), there will be `123` in textbox.. But when I try to catch it in some event (`TextChanged` or `PreviewTextInput`) it catches only 1st char (`1`) and remaining 2 chars disappear